# Negative histogram y-values in Racket

Tags: plot, scheme, racket

I am trying to plot a set of values that includes both positive and negative numbers in Racket.  I have tried using the `discrete-histogram` function from `plot`:

```
(plot 
     (discrete-histogram '(A B C) '(1.2 0.2 -0.4) 
     #:y-min -0.5))
```

The corresponding output doesn't plot anything for the negative value:

[image: My Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`discrete-histogram`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._discrete-histogram%29%29) has one required argument *cat-vals*, so you should use `'((A 1.2) (B 0.2) (C -0.4))` or (if you already have list of X values and list of Y values) `(map list '(A B C) '(1.2 0.2 -0.4))`:

```
#lang racket
(require plot)

(plot (discrete-histogram
       (map list '(A B C) '(1.2 0.2 -0.4)) 
       #:y-min -0.5))
```

In both cases, I see this result:

[image: Histogram]